# Vue.js Bindings in comments

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, vue.js

One very useful feature of Knockout.js is the ability to put bindings in comments. For example, if I want a `<ul>` tag with some dynamically generated `<li>` tags plus the last one that is "Add new Item", in Knockout.js I can do like:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <li><a class="list-group-item" data-bind="text: itemtext"></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-bind="click: $root.charactersView.addCharacter">Add new Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to do such a thing in Vue.js? Thanks

Comment: Do you need to have the binding in comments? Or are you wondering how you can loop through a list?

Comment: No, I don't *need* it but it's the way I can solve the problem of "loop throu a list PLUS add one more item at the end" in Knockout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`v-for` directive](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-for) to loop through the list items and just leave the "Add new Item" in there at the end.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li v-for="item in items">
        <a class="list-group-item" v-text="item.itemtext"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" @click="$root.charactersView.addCharacter">Add new Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also, in the event you'd have a situation where you need to loop through outputting multiple root elements you can use `<template>` tags like `<template v-for="item in items"><div>{{ item.title }}</div><div>For some reason we all don't need our own parent...</div></template>`

Comment: @Bill, with multiple root elements, do you mean multiple `new Vue({...});`? Or multiple components?

Comment: I just meant like, say you wanted to loop through something and put out two elements without a parent for each item you iterate through. A `<template>` tag would be a good way to group them. I mentioned that because it made sense with the question at first but now rereading it I'm not so sure.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand :) Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @BillCriswell @nils Beware the wrath of Internet Explorer - `<template>` tags are not supported! Caused me a big headache last week.

Comment: Hmm. I know template isn't supported in IE but I don't think that should interfere with what Vue is doing with them since it's not actually outputting them. Here's a screen shot from IE9: http://i.imgur.com/vgAdqbE.png